# Passing data between usercontrols c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, report

It's known that there are some solutions similar to this one, but I can't solve my problem with them.
I have two user controls:

- The first one makes a Report object.
- The second one shows it.

I have a main Form that links both controls.

These two controls are created in a DLL, and are added to the
main form like this:

```
//ADDS THE FIRST CONTROL TO THE PANEL CONTROL
  myDll.controlUserReport userControlA = new myDll.controlUserReport();
  panelControl1.Controls.Add(userControlA);
  userControlA.Dock = DockStyle.Left;

//ADDS THE SECOND CONTROL TO THE PANEL CONTROL
   myDll.controlDocViewer userControlB = new myDll.controlDocViewer();
   panelControl1.Controls.Add(userControlB);
   userControlB.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

How can I pass the Report object, which is created in the first control `controlUserReport` when I click over a button, to the other user control `controlDocViewer`  to show it?

[image]

Comment: The best way would probably create a public property in your `controlUserReport` containing the Report object, and another in `controlDocViewer` to get it

Comment: cn you change the code of the user controls?

Comment: yes I can @MongZhu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use events for this. In `UserControlA` declare the event:

```
//Declare EventHandler outside of class
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object source, Report r);

public class UserControlA
{
    public event MyEventHandler OnShowReport;

    private void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, Report r)
    {
         OnShowReport?.Invoke(this, this.Report);
    }
}
```

In `UserControlB` subscribe to the event and show the report:

```
public class UserControlB
{
    // Do it in Form_Load or so ...
    private void init()
    {
       userControlA.OnShowReport += userControlA_OnShowReport;
    }

    private void userControlA_OnShowReport(object sender, Report r)
    {
        // Show the report
        this.ShowReport(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: how does UserControlB class know about instance of userControlA?

Answer (score 0):

the post above is good except init() method should not be in ControlB, but in the parent form, something like this:

```
public class frmMain : Form
{
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
       // subscribe/glue
       userControlA.OnShowReport += userControlB.OnShowReport;
       userControlB.OnShowReport += userControlA.OnShowReport;
    }



public class UserControlA
{
    public event EventHandlerNodeCopy OnDataCopy;
    public TreeNode NodeCopied { get; set; }

    private void some_method(string z, TreeNode trn)
    {
        OnDataCopy?.Invoke(this, trn);
        ...
    }

    public void frmJsTree_OnDataCopy(object source, TreeNode tn)
    {
        NodeCopied = tn;
    }


public class UserControlB
{
    public event EventHandlerNodeCopy OnDataCopy;
    public TreeNode NodeCopied { get; set; }

    private void another_method(int i, TreeNode trn)
    {
        OnDataCopy?.Invoke(this, trn);
        ...
    }

    public void frmJsTree_OnDataCopy(object source, TreeNode tn)
    {
        NodeCopied = tn;
    }


    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using [BehaviorSubject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211949(v=vs.103)) (requires System.Reactive). Once the **data** is added in the BehaviorSubject, all places that subscribe can see the info. A very basic example:

1. Create a class to represent your data. Ex:
   **DataService.cs**

```cs
public static BehaviorSubject<YourDataType> MyAwesomeData { get; } = new BehaviorSubject<YourDataType> (null);
```

2. In You *UserControlA* (maybe in the clickEvent from the button) or whatever:

```cs
private void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  // Do some stuffs to prepare the data...
  YourDataType myDataReportPrepared = null; // something;

  // Here you update your DataInfo on BehaviorSubject
  DataService.MyAwesomeData.OnNext(myDataReportPrepared);
}
```

3. Finally every place in your solution that uses **subscribe** in that Subject will listen to that data, like for example in your *UserControlB*:

```cs
// This will trigger every time MyAwesomeData.OnNext() is executed.
DataService.MyAwesomeData.Subscribe(item =>
      {
        if (item != null){
           // Do something with it...Like populate some Datagrid...
        }

      });
```